# Cannot connect to an external drive attached to my routers USB

Tags: mount, router, external-hdd

I have been trying to connect to an external WD My Book connected via USB to my TP-Link Archer C9 router and formatted ex-FAT. I've been trying from a terminal on my Ubuntu 20.04 web-server. I always get the same error;
"mount error(2): No such file or directory Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page..."
There IS such a directory and changing permission to full makes no difference.

I've tried

- sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.1/tp-share/ /media/nas/ -o
  user=admin,pass="xxxxxxxxx",
- sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.1/tp-share/sda1 /media/nas/ cifs uid=1000, user, auto, defaults, username=admin, password="xxxxxxxxx", vers=2.0 0 0 and vers=1.0 and vers=6.0
- sudo mount.cifs //198.168.0.1/tp-share /media/nas/ -o user=admin, pass="xxxxxxxxx"
  and every other variation I've read about.
  In every case I get "mount error(2): No such file or directory Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page...". Refering to "man mount.cifs(8) and dmesg" was no help at all

I have tried different mounting points with the same results.

The same computer will see the drive when booted into from Acronis True Image boot disk. I believe Acronis uses a WinPE to boot up. That's how I make backup images of the server. Acronis sees it at //192.168.0.1/tp-share/sda1. But, I tried using this in the command lines above with the same results.

The farthest I gotten so far is with;
- //192.168.0.1/tp-share/ /media/nas/ cifs uid=1000, user, auto, defaults, username=admin, password=*********, vers=1.0 0 0 and 2.0.0.0 and 6.0
This ask for the password but after entering it I get

```
- mount error(2): No such file or directory Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page..."
```

I am about to the point of giving up and just putting another HDD in the server. But this is a substantial external drive and I like to be able to access it if need be.

I haven't even tried doing anything with editing fstab because, I have no way to know what the UUID is.